# 'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-3.5

I am using Python 3.5.2 version on Windows 7 and tried using `python3 app.py`. I am getting this error message:

```
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is there any specific cause about why the `python3` command is not working?

I also verified that the PATH is added to environment variables.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

There is no python3.exe file, that is why it fails.

Try:

> py

instead.

py is just a launcher for python.exe. If you have more than one python versions installed on your machine (2.x, 3.x) you can specify what version of python to launch by

> py -2 or 
>   py -3

Comment: `py.exe` seems to get installed as `C:\Windows\py.exe`. `py -3.5` etc. to select a specific version also works.

Comment: is it only for windows? can't we use it in linux as I have tried its not working?

Comment: Once Python for Windows is installed, does not matter the version, just try "python" instead "python3".

Comment: Or use `python app.py` instead as the executable's name is `python.exe` (if you have added Python to PATH).

Answer (score 47):

You can also try this:
Go to the path where Python is installed in your system. For me it was something like C:\Users\\Local Settings\Application Data\Programs\Python\Python37
In this folder, you'll find a python executable. Just create a duplicate and rename it to python3. Works every time.

[image]

Comment: will this add a python3 interpreter to the system?

Comment: I believe this is the only right way to do it!
Except the path is incorrect, (Turn on hidden items)

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37`

Answer (score 17):

Yes, I think for Windows users you need to change all the `python3` calls to `python` to solve your original error. This change will run the Python version set in your current environment. If you need to keep this call as it is (aka `python3`) because you are working in cross-platform or for any other reason, then a work around is to create a soft link. To create it, go to the folder that contains the Python executable and create the link. For example, this worked in my case in **Windows 10** using [mklink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink):

```sh
cd C:\Python3
mklink python3.exe python.exe
```

Use a (soft) [symbolic link](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/) in **Linux**:

```sh
cd /usr/bin/python3
ln -s python.exe python3.exe
```

Answer (score 10):

Python3.exe is not defined in windows

Specify the path for required version of python when you need to used it by creating virtual environment for your project

#### Python 3

> virtualenv --python=C:\PATH_TO_PYTHON\python.exe environment

#### Python2

> virtualenv --python=C:\PATH_TO_PYTHON\python.exe environment

then activate the environment using

> .\environment\Scripts\activate.ps1

Answer (score 8):

In my case I have a git hook on commit, specified by admin. So it was not very convenient for me to change the script (with python3 calls).

And the simplest workaround was just to copy **python.exe to python3.exe**.

Now I could launch both **python** and **python3**.

Comment: This worked for me on windows (if windows has real links - let us know!):

```copy "C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\Python310\python3.exe"```
  And then verify with: 
```python3 --version```

Answer (score 5):

If python2 is not installed on your computer, you can try with just python instead of python3

Answer (score 2):

> For Python 27

```
virtualenv -p C:\Python27\python.exe django_concurrent_env
```

> For Pyton36

```
 virtualenv -p C:\Python36\python.exe django_concurrent_env
```

Answer (score 1):

Enter the command to start up the server in that directory:
**py -3.7 -m http.server**

Answer (score 0):

I had a related issue after installing windows 11, where **python3** in cmd would open the windows store. I was able to sort it out between this post and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58754860/cmd-opens-windows-store-when-i-type-python). In short, I reinstalled python and made sure to add it to PATH. Then, in settings, Apps > Apps & Features > App Execution aliases. Here, all I had to do was make sure that every single python .exe (including idle and pip) were turned off EXCEPT FOR the python3.exe alias. Now it works like a charm.

FWIW:
The root of this issue is not with you or with python. Apparently, Microsoft wanted to make installing python easier for young kiddos getting interested in coding, so they automatically add an executable to PATH. For those of us that already have this executable, it can cause these issues.

Answer (score 0):

Found out instead press the play button the top right and it should work in visual studios:

***Do not disable according to first answer***

Saying python3 in the command will not work by default.

After figuring out the problem with the modules (Solution): https://youtu.be/paRXeLurjE4

Summary:
To import python modules in case of problem to import modules:

Hover over python in search:
Click open in folder
Hover over and right click
click properties
copy everything in path before \python.exe
close those windows

For cmd (administrator):
cd --path that was copied--
then python -m pip install --upgrade pip
cd Scripts
pip install "Name of Package" such as pip install --module (package) --

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Im on win10 and have 3.7, 3.8 and 3.10 installed.

For me "python" launches version 3.10 and does not accept commands (like -3.7), "py" launches newest version but does accept commands, and "python3" does nothing.

Uninstalled 3.10 and "python" now does nothing, and "py" launches 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to add a comment, but the `mlink` option presented in this answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/55229666/8441472  by @Stanislav preserves cross-platform shebangs at the top of scripts (`#!/usr/bin/env python3`) and launches the right python.

(Even if you install python from python.org, Windows will direct you to the app marketplace nowadays if you type `python3` on the command line. If you type `python` on the same cli it will launch the python.org version repl. It leads to scripts that generate no output, but more likely silently failed completely. I don't know ho common this is but have experienced it on a couple of different devices)

If you have this at the top of your script to ensure you launch python3 and don't feel like editing everything you own, it is not a bad approach at all... lol.