# Trying to create a virtual env on Windows 7, using Python 3.6.2

Tags: python

The documentation tells me to type `python3 -m venv myenv`  into the command prompt, assuming the directory I'd like is called `myenv`. However, when I do this, I get:

"python3 is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I have not seen this addressed on here, or in the documentation. My installation seems to have run correctly, because simply typing `python` shows me what it's supposed to show.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910730/python3-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program)

Comment: What does `python --version` show you?

Comment: It shows Python 3.6.2.

Comment: Then you can simply do `python -m venv myenv`.

Comment: I tried this, and did not get an error, but I also got no reply from the cmd prompt. How do I test if this worked? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: If you see a folder named `myenv` then the command worked as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python3 is not in your "search path"

You need to alter the Windows PATH value so the Python3.exe module is found.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain how to do this or point me to a resource which succinctly explains it?

Comment: Open a command window  and type path. What comes back will be the command path, this is where the OS looks for files/settings etc in addition to the directory you are currently sitting in. So assuming you have Python3 install say in c:\MyStuff\Python3   if you do not see that value in the "PATH" output your python3 program will not start. To modify the path  Start - Settings - Control Panel - System - Advanced tab - Environment Variables button -  System Variables, select Path, then click Edit. I suggest you append your directory to the PATH value.