# why python3 command shows error that it is not found

Tags: python, flask

while running **python3 -m venv** on windows

it shows error

`'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

Comment: It looks like you missed a space before the dash going by the error.

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been discussed, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910730/python3-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program) for example. So:

First: Did you verify that the path was added to environment variables?

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) for more details on adding the path to environment variables (**Section 3.3. Configuring Python**).

Secondly:
There is a "**Python launcher**" for Windows. It's an utility which aids in locating and executing of different Python versions. It allows scripts (or the command-line) to indicate a preference for a specific Python version, and will locate and execute that version.

Unlike the PATH variable, the launcher will correctly select the most appropriate version of Python. It will prefer per-user installations over system-wide ones, and orders by language version rather than using the most recently installed version.

This launcher is simply **py**.

To launch your script or virtual environment in command line simply do this:

**py your_script.py** or **py -m venv ENV_DIR**

If you have multiple versions of Python installed (2.x, 3.x), just specify the version you want to run like this:

**py -2.7 your_script.py** or **py -3.6 your_script.py**

If you want the **latest** version of Python 2.x or python 3.x you have installed, try the command:

**py -2 your_script.py** or **py -3 your_script.py**

More details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html)