# Make virtual environment using a different python 3 version

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-3.5, django-dynamic-scraper

I've had issues with installing django dynamic scraper on Windows (pillow installation was causing problems..), but found it works perfectly well on python 3.5.3. As I am currently using python 3.7, I thought it'd be a good idea to work with django dynamic scraper in a virtual environment which uses python 3.5.3.

I installed both versions of python (3.7. and 3.5.3) and set up the environment variables. However, when I tried making a new virtual environment with:

```
virtualenv --python='C:/Python35/python.exe' environment1
```

I get this error:

```
The path 'C:/Python35/python.exe' (from --python='C:/Python35/python.exe') does not exist
```

I've also tried this:

```
virtualenv -p python3.5.3 environment1
```

but got:

`The path python3.5.3 (from --python=python3.5.3) does not exist`

would appreciate any suggestions on how to fix this.

Comment: Have you tried `py -3.5 -m venv environment1`?

Comment: I got this: Python 3.5 not found!
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows
 -3.7-64 *    
Requested Python version (3.5) not installed, use -0 for available pythons

Its a bit weird since my Python3.5.3 is also in enviroment path, and I can see it in the start menue.

Comment: It actually worked. I messed something up with the installations, so once I reinstalled 3.7 and 3.5.3, your suggestion worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `python.exe` in your desired location? Some time it appears to be named as `py.exe` Kindly cross check and for reference you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910730/python3-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program)

Comment: Checked it, and there is no py.exe, but python.exe is in the Python3.5 folder