# python27 and python3 are not not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.7

I want to use python2 and python3.
both of them added in the Environment variable path in `windows 10`.

Environment variable path

```
C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python27
C:\Users\m.daliri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\
C:\Users\m.daliri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\
```

When I calling python27 in Command prompt to show me this error:

```
'python27' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When I calling python3 in Command prompt to show me this error:

```
'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I solve the problem?
How can I call python27 in Command prompt run python27 and python3 run python3?
Is there any problem with my Environment variable path?

Comment: Have you checked that files with those names actually exist? On windows, you only get python.exe

Comment: Check on new terminal/command prompt.

Comment: Hope this answer helps
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41492852/5774004

Comment: @Jonno_FTW yes they are exist