# How do i run python flask and get the link of the localhost?

Tags: python

Hi i am new in Python.

I've tried running this on cmd / powershell : python app.py

but it doesn't do anything.

Since i am using python 3 i also tried: python3 app.py but it came out as

'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910730/python3-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program)

Comment: the error has nothing to do with flask. did you even try to run simple python shell after installation?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add Python3 to your PATH.
2. run `python3 -V`
3. If it prints out the version.

   Test `python3 app.py`. Make sure you have installed required pip packages.

   else

   something wrong with you python3 env
4. If nothing happens when test `python3 app.py`

   check you `app.py`